# MYSQL database IFNULL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display a 'NULL' value as 0 using 'IFNULL' but it returns all rows as null or 0. Everything works fine until I add the 'lounge2' table and the 'lounge2order2' table. The order2.lounge2orderid is 'NULL'. I know it has something to do with 'JOINS' but not sure where or which to implement.

Thanks all...

```
SELECT orders2.orderid, orders2.orderdate, branch2.branchname, COUNT(orders2.garment2orderid) AS 'no gar orders', SUM(garment2.hireprice) as 'total gar sold',
COUNT(orders2.lounge2orderid+IFNULL(orders2.lounge2orderid,0)) as 'No of lounge sales', SUM(lounge2.hirerate)

from orders2, branch2, garment2, garment2order2, lounge2, lounge2order2

WHERE orders2.orderid IN

            (SELECT orders2.orderid FROM orders2 
                WHERE orders2.branchid = 2 
                AND YEAR(orders2.orderdate)= 2011) 

AND branch2.branchid IN

            (SELECT branch2.branchid from branch2
                  WHERE branch2.branchid = orders2.branchid)

AND garment2order2.garment2orderid IN
            (SELECT garment2order2.garment2orderid FROM garment2order2
                WHERE garment2order2.garment2orderid = orders2.garment2orderid)

AND garment2.garmentid IN

            (SELECT garment2.garmentid FROM garment2
                WHERE garment2.garmentid = garment2order2.garmentid)

AND lounge2order2.lounge2orderid IN
            (SELECT lounge2order2.lounge2orderid FROM lounge2order2
                WHERE lounge2order2.lounge2orderid = orders2.lounge2orderid)

AND lounge2.loungeid IN

            (SELECT lounge2.loungeid FROM lounge2
                WHERE lounge2.loungeid = lounge2order2.loungeid)
```

Comment: not sure why it has split it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid `FROM orders2, branch2, garment2, garment2order2, lounge2, lounge2order2` it must be `JOIN ... ON` statement. That would help you to debug and us to understand what your logic and table relations are.

And to have any agregate functions like `SUM` or `COUNT` working you should set `GROUP BY` statement.

Since I have no idea what is your database structure like.

Here is my try:

```
SELECT 
  orders2.orderid, 
  orders2.orderdate, 
  COUNT(orders2.garment2orderid) AS 'no gar orders', 
  branch2.branchname, 
  SUM(garment2.hireprice) as 'total gar sold',
  SUM(IF(orders2.lounge2orderid IS NULL,1,0)) as 'No of lounge sales', 
  SUM(lounge2.hirerate)
FROM orders2
LEFT JOIN branch2
ON branch2.branchid = orders2.branchid
LEFT JOIN garment2order2
ON  garment2order2.garment2orderid = orders2.garment2orderid
LEFT JOIN garment2
ON garment2.garmentid = garment2order2.garmentid
LEFT JOIN lounge2order2
ON lounge2order2.lounge2orderid = orders2.lounge2orderid
LEFT JOIN lounge2
ON lounge2.loungeid = lounge2order2.loungeid)    
WHERE orders2.branchid = 2 
  AND YEAR(orders2.orderdate)= 2011
GROUP BY orders2.orderid
```

Comment: @BrianForbes you may want to double check the counts/sums you are getting if you have orders that have both lounge orders and garment orders. The joins can cause you to have duplicate rows in the result and that would cause your aggregate (SUM/COUNT) numbers to be off. An easy way to check would be to just do a SELECT * and remove the GROUP BY at the end and then you can see the data that is actually getting aggregated.